# Jquery datatables export column as type "Date"

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi I have a table where I have some columns that need to be exported as currency and some to exported as date

But datatables export date as string. I know the reason to export in the format as specified by the user. But my client needs to do some calculations for which he wants the column to be exported as date and not as string. Does anyone have any ideas how to do it?

Note* I have tried orthogonal option=> Its not working

Below is the code that refers to the problem:

```
var buttonCommon = {
        exportOptions: {
            format: {
                body: function ( data, column, row ) {
                    // Strip $ from salary column to make it numeric
                    return column === 5 ?
                        data.replace( /[$,]/g, '' ) :
                        data;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Here the user is converting string column to number. Is there anything with which I can convert string to date?

I have tried this code

```
exportOptions: {
                    format: {
                        body: function ( data, column, row ) {

                        // Strip $ from salary column to make it numeric
                        var customDate = new Date('2016/10/10');
                        customDate = (customDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + customDate.getDate() + '/' +  customDate.getFullYear();

                        return column === 12 ? customDate: data;
                        }
                    },
                    columns: ':visible',
                },
```

But it still returns
10/10/2016
10/10/2016
10/10/2016
10/10/2016

*as string

Comment: SELECT DATE(field_name) from TABLE_NAME ?

Comment: The problem is not while fetching data, Jquery Datatables make it string!

Comment: did you use dataTables library? (min.js)

Comment: @anujeet take a look - https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18

Comment: yes @IceJOKER, I used datatables library, thanks for your finding but I need to change datatype while export and the link you send converts data while sorting

Comment: If you need a javascript date type, try returning with `new Date(year, month, day)`.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude please have a look at the updated description.

Comment: @anujeet this: `customDate = (customDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + customDate.getDate() + '/' +  customDate.getFullYear();` is a string, not a date

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude if I use customDate = new Date('2016/10/10');
then it returns Mon Oct 10 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
**still as a string**

Comment: You are receiving that data in server or in client? How do you retrieve that?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude as a json object

Comment: You can't store a "date" type in a JSON object, you only can store strings and booleans. You should convert the datatype when you receive the JSON, not before the JSON is sended.

Comment: are you getting all data as String in excel , or only date?

Comment: I'm having the same problem... When I try to format the date column in Excel it doesn't work. Excel is not recognizing the column as a date. Did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

hope it may work for you.
add below code according to your code,it detect data which is in the date format dd/mm/yyyy

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.aTypes.unshift(
function ( sData )
{
    if (sData !== null && sData.match(/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(19|20|21)\d\d$/))
    {
        return 'date-uk';
    }
    return null;
}
);
```

and to use this code you have to use this

`<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/type-detection/date-uk.js"/>`

Comment: Hi @yash I dodn't needed a function to check if something coming is date or not. I know that string is coming , I want to convert it into type "date"